# Counting number of lines, words, and characters in a text file

Tags: java, file, input

I am trying to take input from a user, and print the amount of lines, words, and characters in a text file.  However, only the amount of words is correct, it always prints 0 for the lines and characters.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextFileInfoPrinter
{  
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException        
    { 
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);           

            System.out.println("File to be read: ");
            String inputFile = console.next();

            File file = new File(inputFile);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

            int words = 0;
            int lines = 0;
            int chars = 0;

            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                in.next();
                words++;
            }

            while(in.hasNextLine())
            {
                in.nextLine();
                lines++;
            }

            while(in.hasNextByte())
            {
                in.nextByte();
                chars++;
            }

            System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lines);
            System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
            System.out.println("Number of characters: " + chars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
    int words = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int chars = 0;
    while(in.hasNextLine())  {
        lines++;
        String line = in.nextLine();
        chars += line.length();
        words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
    }
```

Comment: good, note that we can count words differently, I used ',' and ' ' as word separators, but you can change it

Answer (score 2):

`in.next();` is consuming all the lines in the first `while()`. After the end of your first while loop, there are no more characters to be read at the input stream.

You should **nest** your character and word-counting **within** a while loop counting lines.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason why you think that:

```
while(in.hasNext())
{
    in.next();
    words++;
}
```

will *not* consume the entire input stream?

It *will* do so, meaning that your other two `while` loops will never iterate. That's why your values for words and lines are still set to zero.

You're probably better off reading the file one character at a time, increasing the character count each time through the loop, and also detecting the character to decide whether or not to increment the other counters.

Basically, wherever you find a `\n`, increase the line count - you should probably also do this if the last character in the stream wasn't `\n`.

And, whenever you transition from white-space to non-white-space, increase the word count (there'll probably be some tricky edge case processing at the stream beginning but that's an implementation issue).

You're looking at something like the following pseudo-code:

```
# Init counters and last character

charCount = 0
wordCount = 0
lineCount = 0
lastChar = ' '

# Start loop.

currChar = getNextChar()
while currChar != EOF:
    # Every character counts.

    charCount++;

    # Words only on whitespace transitions.

    if isWhite(lastChar) && !isWhite(currChar):
        wordCount++

    # Lines only on newline characters.

    if currChar == '\n':
        lineCount++;
    lastChar = currChar
    currChar = getNextChar()

# Handle incomplete last line.

if lastChar != '\n':
    lineCount++;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is

```
int words = 0;
int lines = 0;
int chars = 0;
while(in.hasNextLine())  {
    lines++;
    String line = in.nextLine();
   for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
    {
        if(line.charAt(i)!=' ' && line.charAt(i)!='\n')
        chars ++;
    }
    words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file pointer is set to the end of the file when the 1st while is executed. try this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);


        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            in.next();
            words++;
        }
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            in.nextLine();
            lines++;
        }
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNextByte())
        {
            in.nextByte();
            chars++;
        }
```

Comment: nesting it will have its own problems. The conditions need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert, but I would presume that the `.hasNext`, `.hasNextLine` and `.hasNextByte` all use and increment the same file position indicator. You'll need to reset that, either by creating a new Scanner as Aashray mentioned, or using a RandomAccessFile and calling `file.seek(0);` after each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Cthulhu answer. In your code you can reset your `Scanner` object (`in`).

```
in.reset();
```

This will reset your in object at the first line of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to count for you.

```
String subject = "First Line\n Second Line\nThird Line";  
Matcher wordM = Pattern.compile("\\b\\S+?\\b").matcher(subject); //matches a word
Matcher charM = Pattern.compile(".").matcher(subject); //matches a character
Matcher newLineM = Pattern.compile("\\r?\\n").matcher(subject); //matches a linebreak

int words=0,chars=0,newLines=1; //newLines is initially 1 because the first line has no corresponding linebreak

while(wordM.find()) words++;
while(charM.find()) chars++;
while(newLineM.find()) newLines++;

System.out.println("Words: "+words);
System.out.println("Chars: "+chars);
System.out.println("Lines: "+newLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(in.hasNextLine())  {
        lines++;
        String line = in.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
        {
            if(line.charAt(i)!=' ' && line.charAt(i)!='\n')
        chars ++;
        }
        words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,;:.").countTokens();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
class wordcount
{
    public static int words=0;
    public static int lines=0;
    public static int chars=0;
    public static void wc(InputStreamReader isr)throws IOException
    {
        int c=0;
        boolean lastwhite=true;
        while((c=isr.read())!=-1)
        {
            chars++;
            if(c=='\n')
                lines++;
            if(c=='\t' || c==' ' || c=='\n')
                ++words;
            if(chars!=0)
                ++chars;
        }   
       }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileReader fr;
        try
        {
            if(args.length==0)
            {
                wc(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
                {
                    fr=new FileReader(args[i]);
                    wc(fr);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(IOException ie)
        {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(lines+" "+words+" "+chars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try formatting your answer. To start, for code, indent by using 4 spaces. For more information visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting